# Proof that a ODE system admits symmetric solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, symmetry

I have a ODE system of the form $\dot{x} = f(x)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Now it is claimed that if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is a solution to the system that also $(-x_1,-x_2,-x_3)$ is a solution.

How can I show that this holds, I'm namely not sure how to deal with this? I first thought that I would just show that $-f(x) = f(-x)$  but when computing I saw I wasn't getting anywhere.

ps. If you are wondering why I did not post the ODE system itself, it is because I want to try it for myself.

-edit-

Since I am not really getting response the ODE about which it is about it is

$$\dot{x}_1 = -a_1 x_1 + b_1 x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 = -a_2 x_2 + b_2 x_1 x_3 \\
\dot{x}_3 = -a_3(x_3 - \lambda) - b_3 x_1 x_2
$$

-edit 2-

A friend of mine told me that if I would calculate the fixed points of the system with $(-x_1,-x_2,-x_3)$ that they give the same fixed points as $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and that it would imply that the solutions are the same? But I cannot see how this would imply that.

-edit 3- apparently there was a error in the exercise that I had. I had to proof that if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ then $(-x_1,-x_2,x_3)$ was also a solution and not $-x_3$. Subsituting then these variables then in the system delivers the same state space system.

Comment: What about $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2$ ?

Comment: @Amr for this case it holds that $f(x) = f(-x)$. The solution is $-1/t$ for your system and $1/t$ for $-\dot{x}$. So I should rather have checked $f(x) = f(-x)$? Or was it just a counter example?

Comment: in your system if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$  is a solution then $(-x_1,-x_2,x_3)$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ and $-x$ are both solutions, $\dot{x} = f(x)$ while $\dfrac{d}{dt}(-x) = -\dot{x} = f(-x)$, so it must be true that $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

Comment: Okay so there must be something fishy going on here... since it does not seem to hold that $f(-x) = -f(x)$ in my case, or I must have made a calculation error, let me recompute.

Comment: I suppose you are claiming that this does not hold for all $f$